# python django No module named 'psycopg2' error

Tags: python, django

After completing the installation of python djnago perfectly. When running a command

`"python manage.py runserver"`

getting an error like

> raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e) django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named 'psycopg2'

Comment: Did you install `psycopg2`?

Answer (score 0):

Did you install dev packages? assuming that you have already installed psycopg2
if not and if you are on ubuntu do this `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev python-dev`

Answer (score 0):

First Install its dependencies,

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-psycopg2
```

Then install psycopg2 python module,

```
pip install psycopg2
```

If it shows error then install this and try above ,

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```